# django rest framework nested serializer crud operations . what required is to create a api which should be called only once to perform crud operations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ("admin","ADMIN"),
        ("staff","STAFF")
        )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=256,choices=ROLE_CHOICES)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        users_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
        # for user_data in users_data:
            # User.objects.create(**user_data)
        return profile
```

I want to use nested serializer here to do crud operations.I have written a code for post method i am calling the profile serializer in my views.

Comment: You haven't pasted what you've tried

Comment: okay i will do it.please check now

Comment: What is the problem? Also you do not need many for nesting here, just `user = UserSerializer()` is enough.

Comment: okay thanks. the problem  is solved you are correct due to many it was showing some error.